# Evaluate a string in an XQuery function while maintaining context

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic, exist-db

In marklogic, how can I evaluate a string (using `xdmp:value()`, `xdmp:eval()`, or ??) in a function and maintain still maintain context? (I'm able to do this in eXist with `util:eval-inline()`.)

Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

**XQuery**

```
let $predicate := "val='1234'"
let $xml :=
    <doc>
        <test>
            <val>abcd</val>
        </test>
        <test>
            <val>1234</val>
        </test>
    </doc>

return $xml/test[xdmp:value($predicate)]
```

**Output** (which is what I wanted/expected):

```
<test>
  <val>1234</val>
</test>
```

The issue I'm having is when I try to put `xdmp:value()` in a function:

**XQuery**

```
declare function local:value($string as xs:string) as item()* {
  xdmp:value($string)
};

let $predicate := "val='1234'"
let $xml :=
    <doc>
        <test>
            <val>abcd</val>
        </test>
        <test>
            <val>1234</val>
        </test>
    </doc>

return $xml/test[local:value($predicate)]
```

This returns the following error:

```
[1.0-ml] XDMP-MISSINGCONTEXT: (err:XPDY0002) val -- Missing context item
```

I'm able to do this in eXist (below); is it possible to do this in marklogic? I'm also trying to keep the local function signatures the same.

**XQuery (works in eXist)**

```
declare function local:value($string as xs:string) as item()* {
  util:eval-inline(.,$string)
};

let $predicate := "val='1234'"
let $xml :=
    <doc>
        <test>
            <val>abcd</val>
        </test>
        <test>
            <val>1234</val>
        </test>
    </doc>

return
    $xml/test[local:value($predicate)]
```

**Output** (which is what I wanted/expected):

```
<test>
  <val>1234</val>
</test>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd have to pass the context node to your function.

```
declare function local:value($context as node(), $string as xs:string)
as item()*
{
  $context/xdmp:value($string)
};

let $predicate := "val='1234'"
let $xml :=
  <doc>
        <test>
            <val>abcd</val>
        </test>
        <test>
            <val>1234</val>
        </test>
    </doc>
return $xml/test[local:value(., $predicate)]
```

Or just:

```
let $predicate := "val='1234'"
let $xml :=
  <doc>
        <test>
            <val>abcd</val>
        </test>
        <test>
            <val>1234</val>
        </test>
    </doc>
return $xml/test[xdmp:value($predicate)]
```

Both of those work for me with 7.0-2.3

```
<test>
  <val>1234</val>
</test>
```

Comment: I could've sworn this was the first thing I tried. :-) Works perfect. Thank you Sir!

Comment: Also, your second example ("Or just:") is exactly the same as my first example and did indeed work as expected.

Comment: Yes, I see that. Have you thought about writing up the use case for this? It might be interesting, but I can't tell from the test case.